# On the derived subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=P \ltimes Q $, where $P=Q_8$ and $|Q|=q$ is a prime number. Let $G$ has the following presentation.
$$\langle {x,y,z} \mid {x^q=y^4=z^4=[x,y]=1, y^z=y^{-1}, y^2=z^2, x^z=x^{-1}} \rangle.$$ 
I want to show that $G^{\prime}=Q \times Z(Q_8)$.

MY TRY: We have $Q=[Q,P] \le G^{\prime}$. Also we conclude from above that $Z(Q_8) \trianglelefteq G$. Thus $Q \times Z(Q_8) \trianglelefteq G$, and so $G^{\prime} \le QZ(Q_8)$. It is sufficinet to show that $Z(Q_8) \le G^{\prime}$.

Comment: Note that center of $Q_8$ is generated by $y^2=[z,y]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To abelianize a presentation, just remove all the conjugates: so $y=y^{-1}$; in other words, $y^2=1$ in $G/G'$. Also $y^2=z^2=1$, and $x=x^{-1}$. Thus $G'$ is (normally) generated by the elements $x^2,y^2,z^2$. Assuming $q$ is odd, this means your commutator contains $Q=\langle x\rangle$ and $Z(P)=\langle y^2\rangle$.